# PHP MySQL: Proper/easier way to implement dynamic filtering

Tags: php, mysql

I need suggestion on approach or algorithm or tools to handle my needs; **Dynamic Filtering in SQL**.

I'm using PHP as the backend. I create result filtering at frontend like this:

[image]

When click OK, I send JSON data using:

```
JSON.stringify($('#modalFilter input, #modalFilter select').serializeArray())
```

And this is the data:

```
"[
    {"name":"parameter","value":"state"},
    {"name":"operator","value":"contains"},
    {"name":"value","value":"mel"},
    {"name":"parameter","value":"dateappoint"},
    {"name":"operator","value":"begin"},
    {"name":"value","value":"13/12/2017"}
]"
```

My problem is here. At the backend (PHP), after some massaging (bind param, execute query, etc), I come out with a **very huge and ugly** SQL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sample_staff
WHERE

    CASE WHEN 'state_contains' = ? THEN state LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') END
    CASE WHEN 'state_notcontains' = ? THEN state NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') END
    CASE WHEN 'state_is' = ? THEN state = ? END
    CASE WHEN 'state_isnt' = ? THEN state <> ? END
    CASE WHEN 'state_begin' = ? THEN state LIKE CONCAT(?,'%') END
    CASE WHEN 'state_end' = ? THEN state LIKE CONCAT('%',?) END

    CASE WHEN 'dateappoint_contains' = ? THEN dateappoint LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') END
    CASE WHEN 'dateappoint_notcontains' = ? THEN dateappoint NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') END
    CASE WHEN 'dateappoint_is' = ? THEN dateappoint = ? END
    CASE WHEN 'dateappoint_isnt' = ? THEN dateappoint <> ? END
    CASE WHEN 'dateappoint_begin' = ? THEN dateappoint >= STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%y') END
    CASE WHEN 'dateappoint_end' = ? THEN dateappoint <= STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d/%m/%y') END
```

The above sample SQL just cater for 2 conditions (state and dataappoint) but in real situation, I have to cater more. And I hope to avoid store procedure just to loop the conditions.

I heard about doctrine but still not sure whether the tool could cater my needs or it's completely different purpose.

Comment: Curious why your JSON is in triple pairs instead of a single object per filter. For example, why not: `{filter:"state",operator:"contains",value:"mel"}`

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery QueryBuilder (http://querybuilder.js.org/). It handles your needs and have extensive backend packages to support.

Comment: @Tigger, because each set of filter use the same name and id. When click the add button, I simply clone() the row thus producing same html

Comment: @Ben, thank you. I'm hoping for suggestion like this. Mind to reply as answer instead of comment so I can mark as accepted answer

Comment: How large is the dataset?

Comment: Not sure. Typical system used by department (2000 users). Dataset will grow. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [jQuery QueryBuilder](http://querybuilder.js.org/). It handles your needs and have extensive backend packages to support.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please put this in question comment section